# Why can't this function be used as a loss function?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, loss-functions

In a discussion, a friend mentioned that the function below cannot be optimized so it can't be used in a learning algorithm.

$$E_{in} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^N (h(x_n) \ne f(x_n))$$

Why can't this function be used as a loss function?

**The Context**

This is about machine learning and minimizing the error on a dataset $D$ of size $N$.
I'm talking about comparing the algorithm predictions against the actual outcome recorded from the real world. Comparing a prediction against its real value using a cost function.

$f$ is the "true" mapping and $h$ is my "model".

$h$ should approximate $f$.

Would someone, please, explain why it isn't differentiable as well?

Comment: What are you optimising here? (Also probably you have a parenthesis missing...)

Comment: How are we to understand $(h(x_n) \ne f(x_n))$? It is not clear what is the functional form here.

Comment: If what you're trying to say is that one of $h$ and $f$ is the "true" mapping and the other is your "model", and you are counting the proportion of exactly correctly modeled points, then yes you can "optimize" it. If there are no model constraints, any interpolant of the data will give you exactly 0 error (there are infinitely many). It's unlikely that a model chosen in this way will generalize well at all, however.

Comment: Do you mean to have an indicator function or something inside the sum (so that you "count the misses")? It *can* be used as a loss function ,and it *can* be optimized ... but it doesn't have a derivative; it would require combinatorial-optimization methods (which are typically not practical for large problems)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The loss function in the original post seems like a [**0-1 loss**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function#0-1_loss_function) divided by $N$, which is in fact the ultimate goal of most of classification settings. Actually, 0-1 loss divided by $N$ is equivalent to the [**accuracy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_of_binary_classifiers#Single_metrics) metric.

What your friend said is that it is difficult to use 0-1 loss directly for training a model. This is true for many reasons, but mostly because the loss is not differentiable. Many other loss functions used in classification, for example the likelihood of data, can be viewed as **approximations of 0-1 loss**.

However, since the 0-1 loss is so intuitive and straightforward, the loss function is often measured during the training and assessing models. For me, I would love to print out both likelihood and 0-1 loss.

Comment: It's not the differentiability that's the problem, but the lack of continuity. Non-differentiable loss functions are routinely used in machine learning, for instance, the hinge loss.

Comment: The hinge function is differentiable.

Comment: You mentioned 0-1 can't be used then later on you mentioned it is just accuracy. Accuracy metrics is common. ???? I don't understand,

Comment: @AaronDefazio Thank you for pointing out. Yes, it is the lack of continuity that hinders the direct application of 0-1 loss, and I just put that in "many reasons" in my post.

Comment: @thc however the hinge function does have a non-differentiable point (that's where the "hinge" is), doesnt it?

Comment: @PlayStarCraftOkLetsGo I need to clarify. 0-1 loss, which is almost the same as the accuracy, is "easy to evaluate but difficult to optimize with respect to". Because of non-differentiability and the lack of continuity.

Comment: To clarify, the definition of a differentiable function is one that is differentiable at every point. Both the hinge loss and 0-1 loss are differentiable almost everywhere, but they are not differentiable.

Comment: @AaronDefazio, it IS differentiable as defined in TensorFlow and probably other ML platforms.  Check the source code:  double PrimalLossDerivative(... if (label * wx < 1) { return -label * example_weight;   } return 0; }}.  At any rate, I find the distinction pedantic and not really insightful.

Answer (score 3):

A loss function must be differentiable to perform gradient descent.  It seems like you're trying to measure some sort of 1-accuracy (e.g., the proportion of incorrectly labeled samples).  This doesn't have a derivative, so you can't use it.  Instead, use cross entropy.

Comment: Gradient decent is only one of the optimization algorithms, there is a huge number of them beyond GD. So it really doesn't matter if something works or not with GD unless this question asked about GD.